# How do I get a Tabs Screen to show above a view in react native with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo to build a react native app. I am very new to react-native.

I have the following layout in app/_layout.js:

```
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";
import { BlurView } from 'expo-blur';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';    

export default function Layout() {
    return <>
        <StatusBar style="light"/>
        <View>
            <LinearGradient colors={['red','blue']} style={styles.gradient}/>
        </View>
        <Tabs 
            screenOptions={{ 
                tabBarStyle: { position: 'absolute' }, 
                tabBarBackground: () => (
                    <BlurView tint="dark" intensity={100} />
                ),
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarLabelStyle: {color: 'white'}
            }}
        />
    </>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    gradient: {
        height: '100%'
    }
})
```

In the same directory I have additional files for each screen.

The linear gradient is showing above the content in the screens.  I want the view with the linear gradient to be the background, and the screen content to show above it.  I'm not sure what to do.  I've tried setting the view with the gradient to position: 'absolute' and using z-index, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: did you try wrapping the tabs inside LinearGradient?